# How do expandable objects in Stripe work with Python?

Tags: python, stripe-payments

Stripe's [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api/expanding_objects?lang=python) is broken. Normally once you select Python, it will convert the curl to Python code, but it's not.

Maybe someone here will know.

Trying to expand a `charge` object into it's `payment_intent` object.

[image]

Here's the code:

```
212     if event.type == 'charge.succeeded':
213         charge = event.data.object # contains a stripe.PaymentIntent
214         session = None
215         for co in stripe.checkout.Session.list().data:
216             print(co.payment_intent)
217             payment_intent = stripe.PaymentIntent.retrieve(co.payment_intent)
218             if len(payment_intent.charges.data) > 0:
219                 if charge == payment_intent.charges.data[0]:
220                     session = co
```

Comment: Please show your python code that has the problem.

Comment: I assume it would be `Stripe.Charge.retrieve('chargeID', expand=['payment_intent'])`

Comment: @Barmar Added. Code worked fine for about 3 years. Now all of a sudden I can't get the session from a charge event.

Comment: I'm trying to simplify this bigger problem into a small question. Maybe expanding with the code you suggested will help me work back to the Session.

Comment: What does `print(co.payment_intent)` show?

Comment: If you use `expand=['payment_intent']` you shouldn't need to retrieve it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Stripe has some detailed documentation around expansion [here](https://stripe.com/docs/expand) with use-cases and examples in each of their languages.

Looking at your example code though you seem to be looking for the Checkout Session associated with a given Charge. What you can do is use the List Checkout Sessions [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/list) and pass the `payment_intent` parameter with the id of the PaymentIntent associated with the Charge you got in that Event. Your code could look like this:

```
if event.type == 'charge.succeeded':
    charge = event.data.object # contains a stripe.Charge
    sessions = stripe.checkout.Session.list(payment_intent=charge.payment_intent)
    session = sessions.data[0]
    ...
```

Usually with Checkout though you don't listen to `charge.succeeded` Events specifically. Instead you would listen to `checkout.session.completed` and do fulfillment from that Event. See their docs [here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfill-orders).